# Automate highlight text and add note annotations in Preview

Tags: automator, preview

When annotating a PDF in Preview I regularly highlight text then add a note to that highlight. This is a frustrating process as I can do the first bit with a keyboard shortcut, but must then right-click the highlight to add a note to it. I want to be able to do all this with a single key combination. Any ideas how to make this possible?

Comment: Preview is sadly not scriptable, so any solution will have to employ GUI scripting, which is inherently going to be clunkier.

Comment: Have you looked at Skim.app?